# Angular directive does not load in browser/doesn't work

Tags: angular

Working trough an angular tutorial I've just created my first directive. Unfortunately it does not work as expected.

I've searched google as well as stackoverflow for answers on how to solve this problem, but couldn't find anything relevant.

This is the definition of the directive:

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHover]'
})
export class HoverDirective implements OnInit {
  @HostListener('style.color')
  fontColor: string;

  hover: string;

  @Input()
  get appHover() { return this.fontColor; }
  set appHover(value) {
    if (value.trim() === '') {
      return;
    }

    this.fontColor = value;
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.fontColor === undefined) {
      this.fontColor = 'red';
    }
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  onMouseEnter() {
    this.fontColor = this.hover;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  onmouseleave() {
    this.fontColor = undefined;
  }
}
```

Then I import it into the utils module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HoverDirective } from './hover.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HoverDirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class UtilsModule { }
```

Finally here's my app.component.html template:

```html
<header>
  <h1 appHover='red'>Benutzer</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <app-user-list [ngStyle]="style">
  </app-user-list>
</main>

<footer>
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="company">
    <img *ngSwitchCase="'omega'" src="../assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
    <img *ngSwitchCase="'alphaAndOmega'" src="../assets/img/alphaAndOmega.jpg" alt="logo">
    <img *ngSwitchDefault src="../assets/img/angularLogo.png" alt="angular">
  </ng-container>

  <img *ngIf="showOmega; else elseBlock" src="../assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
  <button id="logo" (click)="toggleLogo()">
    Zeige Logo "Alpha and Omega"
  </button>

  <ng-template #elseBlock>
    <img src="../assets/img/alphaAndOmega.jpg" alt="logo">
  </ng-template>
</footer>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If I checked with google debug tools, I see that the script "hover.directive.ts" is not loaded; and thus the directive does not work at all.

Any help and pointers on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Patrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your UtilsModule imported to an other module (SharedModule)? If so, you must export the directive to use it.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HoverDirective],
  exports: [HoverDirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class UtilsModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `UtilsModule` inside your `AppModule` by importing it. In that case the `HoverDirective` can be made accessible to the other module only if it's parent module (`UtilsModule`) exports it. So your `UtilsModule` should be :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HoverDirective],
  exports: [HoverDirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class UtilsModule { }
```